# why my localhost server is down symfony 3?

Tags: html, symfony

i m trying to save data to my base and everything is ok and suddenly when i click at add button in form this screen appears
[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNTaZ.png)

i havent understand why and where is the problem causing that

in my controller action i have tried to dump my object that i want to add in my database and i got this output so everything is ok  [object data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87aFW.png)

this is my controller action

```
    public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod("post")){
        $title = $request->get('title');
        $image = $request->get('image');
        $genre  = $request->get('genre');
        $date = $request->get('date');
        $director = $request->get('director');
        $stars = $request->get('stars');
        $trailer = $request->get('trailer');
        $synopsis = $request->get('synopsis');


        $movie = new Movie();
        $movie->setTitle($title);
        $movie->setImage($image);
        $movie->setGenre($genre);
        $movie->setDate($date);
        $movie->setDirector($director);
        $movie->setStars($stars);
        $movie->setTrailer($trailer);
        $movie->setSynopsis($synopsis);
        dump($movie);
        die();

        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($movie);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response("film added");

    }
    return $this->render('FilmsFilmsBundle:Pages:add.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found that my input date is causing this problem 
so i changed it by `<input type="text">` and i changed  the annotation for my date variable in my entity from date to string and everything is working fine

Answer (score -1):

There is obviously a code error there. If you are using apache, you can check the error log on linux using

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error-log.txt
```

on windows it's usually `<base path to apache install>\logs`